# How to run function on page load?

Tags: flutter

#### I want to set the location as visited while using StatefulWidget.

### How do I make it just once?

If I run `setLocationAsVisited` function in `_LocationScreenState` , then will it run forever (60fps)?

```dart
class LocationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final location;
  LocationScreen({
    @required this.location,
  });
  @override
  _LocationScreenState createState() => _LocationScreenState();
}
class _LocationScreenState extends State<LocationScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setLocationAsVisited(widget.location.id);
-----------
  }
 }
setLocationAsVisited(int visitedID) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.setInt('lastID', (visitedID));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make use of the `initState` method which runs once when the widget is first build.

```dart
class LocationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final location;

  LocationScreen({
    @required this.location,
  });

  @override
  _LocationScreenState createState() => _LocationScreenState();
}
class _LocationScreenState extends State<LocationScreen> {

  // The init state function.
  @override
  void initState() {
    setLocationAsVisited(widget.location.id);

    // Make sure to call super.initState();
    super.initState();
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Return the widgets.
    return ...
```

Comment: If it was StatelessWidget then it would already run just once isn't it?

Comment: Only outside of the build method it would. But, it's best practice to do any kind of logic/requests in a stateful widget :)

Comment: I can not run the `setLocation` function outside the build method. it says: `'setLocationAsVisited' must have a method body because 'LocationScreen' isn't abstract.`

Comment: Could you maybe add the function `setLocationAsVisited` to your question?

Comment: it's an async function so I better use StatefulWidget instead.

Comment: In that case, yes!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231814/discussion-between-cem-kaan-and-youri-lieverdink).